# confusing fork system call

Tags: c++, c, unix, fork

i was just checking the behaviour of fork system call and i found it very confusing.
i saw in a  website that

***Unix will make an exact copy of the parent's address space and give it to the child. Therefore, the parent and child processes have separate address spaces***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(void)
{
pid_t pid;
char y='Y';
char *ptr;
ptr=&y;
pid = fork();
if (pid == 0)
{
y='Z';
printf(" *** Child process  ***\n");
printf(" Address  is %p\n",ptr);
printf(" char value is %c\n",y);
sleep(5);
}
else
{
sleep(5);
printf("\n ***parent process ***\n",&y);
printf(" Address  is %p\n",ptr);
printf(" char value is %c\n",y);
}
}
```

the output of the above program is :

```
 *** Child process  ***
 Address  is 69002894
 char value is Z

 ***parent process ***
 Address  is 69002894
 char value is Y
```

so from the above mentioned statement it seems that child and parent have separet address spaces.this is the reason why char value is printed separately and why am i seeing the address of the variable as same in both child and parent processes.?

Please help me understand this!

Comment: Names of variables exists only at compile time for some specific language. At run-time your code uses precise address (for stack it uses offset from some register, and memory pointers is relocated after program is mapped to memory). As well, as your example states - just before forking current process you store pointer in some place (it even can be some external storage). So if fork() will cause change of memory layout - your program will not be able to work further after returning from that syscall.

Comment: The answers are right, but in your actual exemple, there's another problem.  You are storing the address of Y inside ptr before the fork, so ptr contain '69002894'.  After the fork, ptr will still contain that value, both in the parent and in the child processes, even if the addres of Y would have changed in one of the two process.  To be correct, you have to print &Y in your printf statement.

Comment: @laurent   after the fork ptr will be copied to child process also.
this implies that child and parent will have two different ptr's.
please check by chnaging the statements as suggested by yourself in printf.you will get the same result.

Comment: Yes, I know that you will get the same result, for the reasons mentioned in the answers (virtual address space).  What I was saying is that, _IF_ the address of y would have been different in the child's process (which everybody agree that it's not the case), the value of PTR would still be the address of Y in the parent's process instead of being the address of Y in the child process.  So you would not see the difference in your printfs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically the concept of virtual memory gives a view to the process as if it is the sole owner of the system. It feels it has access to the complete memory.

But in reality, the OS gives it only a virtual memory which is mapped to the actual memory by the OS by using MMU.

So, what happens in your case is, each process (parent and child) have their own address space. And this is separate for both. Now here, the address space refers to the virtual address space.

So, though both in parent and child the same address is present, this is just the virtual address. and each maps to a different physical address.

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 6):

You're right.  As soon as you call `fork()`, two identical processes exist.  Therefore, the address of `y` is the same for the copy of y in each process.  The only difference between the two processes is that in one, `fork()` returned `0`, and in the other it returned the PID of the child.  Your program is using that information to do different behaviour in the parent and child, so you get the appropriate output.

In "real life", operating systems do a lot of optimizations to make `fork()` *really* fast.  That means that the actual physical behaviour probably doesn't involve a complete copy of the memory space.  Logically, however, you can treat it as such.

Comment: but what about the the comment of "separate address spaces fro child and parent?"

Comment: @benjamin, yeah they're different processes, so each has it's own separate virtual memory space.  They're completely independent as soon as `fork()` returns.

Comment: "Seperate address spaces" means that a given address in one process refers to a seperate bit of memory from the same address in the other process.  That's how address 69002894 in your example is able to store both `X` and `Y` at the same time - "address 69002894 in process A" is a distinct location from "address 69002894 in process B".

Answer (score 6):

They have separate address space -- that is precisely why the same memory address is allowed to have different values. A memory address only has meaning in the context of a process.

Answer (score 3):

Address 221 P Street is a separate building from address 221 C Street.  Their contents differ even though they have the same address number.

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace `pid` with `ptr` .
To get the parent and child ID you must use `pid` in `printf(" Address  is %p\n",pid);` instead of `ptr`. After `fork()` program runs in two parts. One is child and the other one is parent. If you call for address from a variable that used before `fork()` ,you will get the same result both for parent and child.